# SQL Updating Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-update

The web hosting company changed my Php Myadmin version over the weekend and the update code I have used for a year to update stock in Mysql no longer works.

Orig code

```
update uc_product_stock x set x.stock = (select y.stock from import y where trim(x.SKU) = trim(y.SKU))
```

It now brings back the following error

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: are you sure that it's not supposed to return more than one row? What do you get when you run the sub-query on its own.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE x 
    SET x.stock = y.stock 
    FROM uc_product_stock x
        INNER JOIN import y 
            ON TRIM(x.SKU) = TRIM(y.SKU))
```

Comment: Won't this still result in multiple values per X row in Y?

Comment: @JNK - This should run, but its gonna update x.stock to any of the values of y.stock

Comment: +1 - It's still a workaround.  Probably should let him know he will have indeterminate values in the updated field though.

Answer (score 2):

Your subquery returns multiple values, and SQL doesn't know which one you want to assign to your row.

You have to get the subquery returning single values.

Options are:

- Make the subquery more specific (add extra `WHERE` filters, `JOIN`, etc)
- Use a `TOP` clause to only return one row - `SELECT TOP 1....`